# Gerar nova matriz removendo determinada coluna e linha

Tags: r, matriz

Gostaria de saber se existe algum função do R que eu consiga gerar uma nova matriz eliminando determinada coluna e linha.

```
Matriz_1 
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,]   0.0 136.6 123.7 124.3 128.0 123.7
[2,] 136.6   0.0   8.8  15.9   5.7  15.4
[3,] 123.7   8.8   0.0   7.5   4.6   6.9
[4,] 124.3  15.9   7.4   0.0  11.7   1.6
[5,] 128.0   5.7   4.6  11.8   0.0  11.2
[6,] 123.7  15.3   6.9   1.6  11.2   0.0
```

Estes são meus dados:

```
Matrix_1 <- structure(c(0, 136.6, 123.7, 124.3, 128, 123.7, 136.6, 0, 8.8, 
  15.9, 5.7, 15.4, 123.7, 8.8, 0, 7.5, 4.6, 6.9, 124.3, 15.9, 7.4, 
  0, 11.7, 1.6, 128, 5.7, 4.6, 11.8, 0, 11.2, 123.7, 15.3, 6.9, 
  1.6, 11.2, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 6L))
```

Quero que a nova matriz tenha apenas os pontos maiores que 125 (quero analisar pela linha 1).

Nesse caso eu removeria as colunas 3, 4 e 6, e também as linhas 3, 4 e 6, resultando em

```
       [,1]   [,2]  [,5]  
[1,]   0.0  136.6  128.0 
[2,] 136.6   0.0     5.7 
[5,] 128.0   5.7     0.0
```

Em suma, Quero analisar minha primeira linha...dei um exemplo onde quero eliminar da matriz as colunas que tenha um valor superior a 125, analisando a linha 1. Depois de eliminar as colunas eliminar as linha correspondentes. exemplo: se eliminei a coluna 4, eliminar a linha 4. Mas quero preservar os índices e depois salvar num vetor os índices que sobr
aram e minha nova matriz "filtrada".

Comment: Mesmo com a minha edição, a pergunta não faz muito sentido. O que significa "Quero que a nova matriz tenha apenas os pontos maiores que 125"? O que é um ponto em uma matriz? E, mesmo se apenas as colunas com observações maiores do que 125 na linha 1 sejam mantidas, o que a coluna 1 faz no resultado, se o seu valor é 0.0?

Comment: Desculpa se não me expressei bem. Vou tentar de novo. Quero analisar minha primeira linha...dei um exemplo onde quero eliminar da matriz as colunas que tenha um valor superior a 125, analisando a linha 1. Depois de eliminar as colunas eliminar as linha correspondentes. exemplo: se eliminei a coluna 4, eliminar a linha 4. Mas quero preservar os índices e depois salvar num vetor os índices que sobraram e minha nova matriz "filtrada".